# In typescript, why can't I infer a generic super type's type parameter?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to be able to explicitly define a `Base` arg and use it with types that inherit from class `Closure`.

```
abstract class Closure<Base> {
    // Helper functions/types etc. related to Base here
}
```

So that if I had a class, I could explicitly tag it with a type, to use it later.

```
interface A {
    foo(args: { one: string, two: number }): void
}

class B extends Closure<A> implements A {
    foo(args: { one: string, two: number }) { }
}
```

I create a type to infer the `Base` type on any instance that implements `Closure`.

```
type BaseOf<T extends Closure<unknown>> = T extends Closure<infer U> ? U : never;
```

But when I try to infer the `Base` type, I get `unknown`.

```
type b = BaseOf<B> // Why is this unknown?
```

And yet...

```
type b2 = BaseOf<Closure<A>> // This results in A just fine.
```

Why am I unable to infer `A` here, when I've explicitly defined a concrete type?

Comment: `Closure<Base>` is equivalent to `{}`. Add something that references `Base`, and it'll work: https://tsplay.dev/NV3jMm. The reason why it works for `b2` is because TypeScript has seemingly preserved what `T` really is inside `BaseOf`, kinda like this phenomenon: https://tsplay.dev/wRBLYw

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to vr, I ended up with this solution:

```
abstract class Closure<Base> {
    private readonly _base?: Base;
}
```

Which ensures that each generic type instantiation is nominally typed by its type argument!